# Multiple network cards, I lose internet on reboot

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, server, netplan

I really hope you'll take time to read my problem, I've hesitated a lot about asking you because of how complicated it is and I was even wondering how I'm going to explain it.

This is occurring since a good amount of times now and I've searched all the forums without any clear answer on my specific problem.

I've 3 network cards.

enp1s0: a PCIE 10 Gb asus one
enp2s0: the mobo realtek one
enp5s0: a realtek lan card

Please find below my actual yaml file:

```
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
#Asus enp1s0 / Gigabyte enp2s0 / external 1Gbs enp5s0
   enp2s0:
     optional: true
     dhcp4: false
     dhcp6: false
     addresses: [192.168.1.91/24, ]
     gateway4: 192.168.1.254
     nameservers:
       addresses: [192.168.1.91, ]
       search: [XXXX.net]
#   enp1s0:
#     optional: true
#     dhcp4: false
#     dhcp6: false
#     addresses: [192.168.1.77/24, ]
#     nameservers:
#       addresses: [192.168.1.92, 8.8.8.8, ]
#       addresses: [8.8.8.8, ]

   enp5s0:

     optional: true
     dhcp4: false
     dhcp6: false
     addresses: [192.168.1.77/24, ]
     nameservers:
       addresses: [192.168.1.92, ]

 vlans:
   vlan11:
     id: 11
     link: enp2s0

     optional: true
     addresses: [192.168.1.92/24, ]

   vlan12:
     id: 12
     link: enp2s0

     optional: true
     addresses: [192.168.1.93/24, ]
```

Which results in this config

```
ip -c a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.1.91/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.1.77/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp5s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
5: vlan12@enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.1.93/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global vlan12
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: vlan11@enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.1.92/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global vlan11
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Don't mind the DNS addresses because when I lost internet I'm not able to ping even local ip addresses.

Here is what I've tried:

- Make a very basic install only with my cards & google DNS, doesn't work.
- Remove all the lan cards, this work, at the second I connect another lan card to ethernet, it works till I reboot.
- Check Qantia driver and get the latest one for asus lan card, doesn't work, also tried with the two realtek cards and same issue.
- Check Realtek drivers because a version of (forgot which) drivers were buggy, checked it, had the said buggy driver, installed the new one but still the same issue.

That's why I feel helpless about this issue, now here is some info that can help you to understand my issue:

- On the reboot, I lose internet, but it's solved by unplugging the ethernet cables and replugging them, yes it's like magic and nonsense, but this solution works like a charm and all cards & vlans start working updoing disconnecting & reconnecting ethernet cables.
- My router sees only one mac address on his side instead & see my server as one computer with several ip addresses, but the ip -a command shows me that mac addresses are not the same.

If you reached that point, thank you very much and I hope you'll be able to help me to understand that issue that I'm having since my early start with a basic server & setup with only 2 NICS.

Please feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: After you reboot and before you replug the network cables, what is the output of `ip -c a`?  I.e.  is it the same as what you already posted or are there differences?  Also what is the output of networkctl?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by installing NetworkManager as my netplan renderer instead of networkd, using the exact same file and configuration, I just change to NetworkManager as renderer and everything works like a charm.

So it looks like networkd is having problems setting up my NICs, any ideas ?